# Maven Surefire does not find tests

Tags: java, maven, testing, maven-surefire-plugin

I am having difficulties with maven surefire, as it does not run my tests.
I know this question has been asked many times before and I have tried out multiple things all without success

1. I changed the name of my test directory to src/test/java
2. I changed the names of my test to fit the *Test pattern
3. I tried a Junit3 test
4. I tried specifically including a test in the pom

Maybe anyone of you can point out my probably stupid mistake.

My pom is listed below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>BitTrader</groupId>
    <artifactId>BitTrader</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>BitTrader</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
        <sonar.jdbc.url>
            jdbc:h2:tcp://lustigsbusi.ch:9092/sonar
        </sonar.jdbc.url>
        <sonar.host.url>
            http://lustigsbusi.ch:9000
        </sonar.host.url>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <!-- To define the plugin version in your parent POM -->
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>CombinedOrderBookTest.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>

    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-coyote</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.41</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xeiam.xchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>xchange-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xeiam.xchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>xchange-examples</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xeiam.xchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>xchange-bitcoincharts</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xeiam.xchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>xchange-bitstamp</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xeiam.xchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>xchange-btce</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xeiam.xchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>xchange-campbx</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xeiam.xchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>xchange-cavirtex</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xeiam.xchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>xchange-mtgox</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xeiam.xchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>xchange-openexchangerates</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**EDIT**
It works with Dtest.

This is the output of mvn test 
http://pastebin.com/bZ9Mg4Bs

Comment: seems alright to me, try 'mvn clean install -X', this will give you more information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your test-class follows the naming convention, then there's no need to specify the includes.

The real issue is that it seems like 'CombinedOrderBookTest.java' can't be matched.

Comment: I agree I only included it so cause it to see if it would work -> it didn't

Comment: If you run it from cmdline, could you try to add `-Dtest=CombinedOrderBookTest` (indeed, without `.java`)

Comment: This works fine the test is run but I still down know why it doesn't run the tests automatically

Comment: If you run `mvn test -X`, could you paste the output of the surefire-plugin somewhere? There must be a good reason why it's not picking up this test.

Comment: `[DEBUG]   (s) includes = [AllTest]` Where is this value coming from?

Comment: I tried to specifically include AllTest. When I removed it, it immediately worked. My explanation is as follows. I had some other problems like not following the naming conventions in the beginning than I tried including tests specifically which apparently excludes all other tests. The include didn't work and thus no test was run.